# How many connections can OSX support?

Tags: networking, macos, ftp, tcp, sftp

I'm using FTP software and it has an option of using 1-30 connections for uploading.

How many connections (internet) can an operating system like OSX make and how do I know what value to choose?

I found this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741168/how-many-tcp-ip-socket-connections-can-a-systemcomputer-handle) but it doesn't say for Mac OSX or how to determine how many to choose.

Comment: This is talking about concurrent connections to your ftp. How much bandwidth do you have? You connecting from the internet or lan?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart The question is just in general. Upload to FTP, download from FTP, over wireless, over LAN, etc. I'm guessing if I set it to something like 100 connections on my PC the speed would go down at some point because of the limitation of the read or write of the hard drive. My question is more how to determine what to set that value to. If I provided a value would it help? Let's say my upload is 512KB.

Comment: how many people do you expect to connect simultaneously? if just one at a time set it to one. if you expect ten set it to ten.

Answer (score 2):

Increasing the number of connections is only useful if you can push data faster than the site can accept it over a single connection.

The simplest way to test is to do it empirically & check the combined speed. Use something like iStat Menus or any of the myriad ethernet data stream counters. Using a test file of maybe 10 - 50MB, depending on your line speed, upload the test file & at each upload increase the number of simultaneous connections.
Gauge your test figure at about halfway through the upload; the beginning & end will show less-reliable figures. Also bear in mind this may not produce exactly the same numbers if you repeat a test, there will be variance, so 'use your skill & judgement'.

There will be a phase of increase in overall speed, a phase of stability & a phase of decrease, as the number of connections is then using more overhead than the benefit gained by distributing the upload connections.

The sweet spot is the number where you first saw stability.
This may, on a slow line, actually be 1.

More is not always better.

The benefit of this method is it saves the effort of actually calculating your theoretical limit, only to be disappointed at the fact you can never achieve that figure.